# Concatenar Strings em C

Tags: c, string, lógica, concatenação-de-string

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Estou com um problema em Strings utilizando a Linguagem C.

O problema pede pro usuário digitar um nome, depois digitar um caractere especial e por ultimo quantas vezes ele deseja que o caractere seja concatenado com a String. Porém a concatenação só deverá ser realizada com a ultima vogal da String.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char nome[100]="Celular";
char letra[100];
int qtd=0;

printf("Nome definido: %s\n\n", nome);

printf("\nCARACTER que deseja INCLUIR no nome ");
scanf(" %c",&letra);

printf("\nQuantidade de vezes que deseja colocar no nome? ");
scanf(" %d",&qtd);

for(int i=0;i<qtd;i++){

    strncat((nome), letra, 1 );
}

printf("resultado = %s\n ", nome);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}
```

O código vai adicionar o caractere especial no final da string. Porém, não entendi como fazer pra ser adicionado na ultima vogal da string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu fiz a ideia base do programa e irei explicar a logica, porem este programa falha em alguns casos que irei dizer tambem, terá depois de ter algumas validações para este codigo funcionar para os diversos nomes, é util pensarmos no assunto e não fazer logo um `copy paste` no codigo.

Poderá haver algum metodo mais eficiente, ou ate uma função que possa fazer isto, porem a logica terá de ser a mesma.

---

### Lógica

**1. Deverá primeiro localizar a ultima vogal**

**2. deverá puxar para a frente `qtd` de vezes para conseguir colocar a vogal.**

*Ex: `qtd=2`--> celula_ _r, para depois naquele espaço colocarmos a letra que queremos*

**3. Colocarmos a letra no sitio correto**

---

```
char nome[100]="Celular";
char letra;
int qtd=0;
int i, j;
printf("Nome definido: %s\n\n", nome);

printf("\nCARACTER que deseja INCLUIR no nome ");
scanf(" %c",&letra);

printf("\nQuantidade de vezes que deseja colocar no nome? ");
scanf(" %d",&qtd);

for( i=strlen(nome) ; i>-1; i--){ /** 1 **/

    if(nome[i]=='a' || nome[i]=='e' || nome[i]=='i' || nome[i]=='o' || nome[i]=='u' )
    {
        i++;
        break;
    }

}

for(j=strlen(nome); j>=i; j--) /** 2 **/
    nome[j+qtd]=nome[j];

for(j=i; j<qtd+i; j++) /** 3 **/
    nome[j]=letra;

printf("resultado = %s\n ", nome);
```

**[Codigo no ideone](https://ideone.com/Vd1iSt)**

- O nome pode não ter nenhuma vogal, o que pode causar problemas neste programa (por causa do 1º `for`, se não encontrar nada `i` terá valor de `-1` e irá adicionar na mesma)
- Este programa assume que vai ter vogais minúsculas
- Este programa não garante que não atinja o **overflow** no nome, pois pode puxar para a frente de tal maneira que pode atingir mais que 100. Ex: `qtd=100`

Comment: O problema da ausencia de vogais em uma entrada do usuario não poderia ser resolvido utilizando um goto no 1º for ? Caso, nao ache uma vogal direciona diretamente para o final do programa.

Comment: Poderia criar uma variavel `int x=-10` depois no fim do primeiro ciclo colocava `if(x==-10)` fazia o goto para o fim como disse.

Answer (score -1):

Pode-se fazer um controle para capturar vogais maiúsculas e minusculas, como também evitar imprevistos caso uma palavra digitada não tenha uma vogal da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

 char nome[100];
 char temp[100];
 char letra[2];
 int qtd,i,j,k,encontrouVogal = 0;


 printf("Digite um nome:", nome);
 fgets(nome,100,stdin);
 nome[strcspn(nome,"\n")] = 0;

printf("\nCARACTER que deseja INCLUIR no nome: ");
scanf(" %c",letra);

printf("\nQuantidade de vezes que deseja colocar no nome?: ");
scanf(" %d",&qtd);

for(i= strlen(nome); i > -1 ;i--){
   if(nome[i] == 'a' || nome[i] == 'e' || nome[i] == 'i' || nome[i] ==
   'o' || nome[i] == 'u'){
    encontrouVogal = 1;
    break;
  }else if(nome[i] == 'A' || nome[i] == 'E' || nome[i] == 'I' || nome[i] == 'O' || nome[i] == 'U'){
    encontrouVogal = 1;
    break;
  }
}

if(encontrouVogal){

     /* Todos os caracteres encontrados apos a vogal são passados
     para uma string temporaria */
     for(j = i+ 1,k= 0; j < strlen(nome); j++,k++){
       temp[k] = nome[j];
     }
     temp[k] = '\0';

     /* Todos os caraceteres encontrados apos a vogal são removidos */
     for(j = i + 1 ; j < strlen(nome); j++){
       nome[j] = '\0';
     }

     /* A concatenação é feita com o caractere escolhido */
     for(j = 0; j < qtd ; j++){
       strcat(nome,letra);
     }

     /* Todos os caracteres que estão na string temporaria são passados
     novamente para a string nome*/
     strcat(nome,temp);

     printf("resultado = %s\n ", nome);

   }else{
   printf("A palavra digitada nao possui vogais,impossivel concatenar!\n");
  }

 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;

}
```